# Code Length of most Naive Repetition Code

Tags: error-correction, error-mitigation

What is the formula or answer to the following coding: I would like to get logical qubit with logical error rate of $P_L=1E-10$ or $P_L=1E-19$ for Shor's algorithm, but I would like to know how many physical qubits per 1 logical are needed in the case of the **naive **Repetition Code**** / Shor code.

Is there also any simple formula? I just need an **approximation**

For example, in case of surface code, in order to get $P_L=1E-10$ one will need $d=17$ surface code.

Thank you

Comment: The repetition code is a distance 1 code, so no amount of qubits in this encoding will help you out. The Shor code, as far as I know, is just a proof of concept and has never been scaled up to arbitrary distances. In any case for any code you can get bounds by looking at the combinatorial weight of sets of d-1 errors in a single code cycle

Comment: I am trying to find some buzz sentence that is showing the reward that we get from surface codes, relativly to other codes, and in terms of qubits amount. A good answer will be also about another code, LDPC? ayn code that is less good than surface code in terms of qubits amount in some wanted logical error.

Comment: By the way, are you Israeli? I will be happy to contact https://www.linkedin.com/in/ronf6co/

Comment: I agree it would be interseting to see the error rate on various algorithms such as Shor for several codes. Don't know if anyone has done this, but we can just wait for Craig...

Comment: @RonCohen If you want to show that the surface code is better than other codes based on the number of qubits required, you definitely don't want to compare it to more general LDPC codes--the surface code is *terrible* compared to LDPC codes when it comes to the number of qubits.

Comment: So in what manner surface code is better than LDPC? What is it the leading code?